# BIRT Report with JSON Column data to table

Tags: json, birt

I have a PostgreSQL table that stores some information in a JSON column, I'd like to take the data from this JSON column and populate a secondary table in the BIRT report.

I've got the data into a JSON object just fine, I can use it, but table #2 won't populate any data even though there is data in the JSON object.

DataSource1 it attached to DataSet1 which is PostgreSQL. DataSource2 is a scripted DS, and it has Dataset2 attached to it with columns defined.

In dataset1 I have the `OnFetch` function making my JSON array:

```
vars["invoiceData"] = JSON.parse(row["i_invoice"]);
```

Then I have in dataset2 (json dataset) I have this for the `fetch` event setup:

```
// Get the length of the object
len = vars["invoiceData"].labor.length;

count = 0;// Counter used to step through each item in the JSON object.

// Loop through the JSON object adding it to the scripted data source
if(count < len && len != 0) {
  row["hrs"] = vars["invoiceData"].labor[count].hrs;
  row["desc"] = vars["invoiceData"].labor[count].desc;
  row["rate"] = vars["invoiceData"].labor[count].rate;
  row["amount"] = vars["invoiceData"].labor[count].amount;
  count++;
  return true;
}

return false;
```

If I echo out the length of my array it has one row in it, but that table never comes back with anything, always empty on my report.

Comment: did you endup solving this one? I'm currently having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing initialization code with loop code.

Just think about this fragment:

```
count = 0;
if (...) {
    count++;
    return true;
}
return false;
```

You need to split and modify this code. Basically, for a scripted data set you need three things:

- A counter variable (or something similar). This is best declared as a report variable.
- Initialization of the counter variable in the data set's `open` event.
- Using the counter variable in the data set's `fetch` event, eg modifying it and comparing it to the data length.

Your code will return the first data row in an endless loop, because what BIRT does is:

```
open()
while fetch():
    emit the current row
```

Thus, your code is definitely wrong.
OTOH the behavior that you describe doesn't match what I would expect: A never-ending report. So there are probably other errors in your report. What does the "problems" view in the BIRT designer show?